# Unable to download Tensorflow on Python via Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, apple-m1

I am running in to an issue with Tensorflow installation. I have a M1 Mac which has a different set of install instructions. I am running Python 3.12.1, I have removed uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda, created new environments but am not sure how to resolve the issue.

I have tried these instruction sets:

1. [https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
(myenv) manavkhanna@Manavs-MacBook-Pro ~ % conda activate mlp
(mlp) manavkhanna@Manavs-MacBook-Pro ~ % conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: - 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

(mlp) manavkhanna@Manavs-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

2. [https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-macos (from versions: none)
```

Can someone please step through this with me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos`. Are you looking for `python3 -m pip install tensorflow`? https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: That's because tensorflow doesn't support Python 3.12.1. it supports 3.9-3 11. See https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#data

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow does not support for Python 3.12. Your best options are: Python 3.8, 3.9, or 3.10.

Give it a go and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.12.1 isn't supported by tensorflow. Try using 3.11